# Different Behaviors for Touch and Click using Link in A-Frame in Mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, hyperlink, 3d, aframe

I am new to this and need some tips. I want to know if is there some way to optimise an A-Frame page to work fully on Mobile. I made some events and all works well with PC and Mac, but a lot of functions don't work on Mobile (iPhoneX and Android 6), and even using lines like:

```
this.el.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => { 
window.open('https://physi-enabled.glitch.me','_blank');
```

Any ideas? This is the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/building-world?path=index.html:28:62

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4YWt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific enough, but here's a few tips as you requested:

1. Use A-Frame built-in **components**, **primitives** and **util functions** to your advantage. For example there's already [link component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/link.html#sidebar) - you can use it instead of manually attaching `click` events just to open link in new tab.
2. [Look controls](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/look-controls.html#sidebar) is a component that defines mouse and touch behaviors, so you might want to look into it.
3. `AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile` is a function that tells you if the device is mobile, you don't really need your own most of the time.
4. [event-set](https://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/components/event-set/) component might help you reduce all the code related to changing one property on `hover` or `click` etc.
5. Most of the above, if not everything is mentioned in [A-Frame docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/).

Comment: So far i've changed 'click' for 'mouseenter' and works well on mobile, but not in browser. Seems like mouse enter emit a ray, and mousedown emit another. So if i touch the screen it emits two rays. I was thinking make a function that implements the AFRAME.utils... you say, have to try that.